DevExpress WPF SelectComboBox set selected items
I have an issue to set in TokenMode for DevExpress WPF control SelectCOmboBox some items.
I have an xaml for column in my datagrid:
 <!-- Competencies Column with Token ComboBox -->
 <dxg:GridColumn FieldName ="Competencies"  Header="Competencies" Width="200">
     <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <dxe:ComboBoxEdit Name="PART_Editor"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Row.Competencies}"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding Row.SelectedCompetencies}"
                 ValueMember="Id"
                 DisplayMember="Name"
                 ImmediatePopup="False">
                 <dxe:ComboBoxEdit.StyleSettings>
                     <dxe:TokenComboBoxStyleSettings />
                 </dxe:ComboBoxEdit.StyleSettings>
             </dxe:ComboBoxEdit>
         </DataTemplate>
     </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
 </dxg:GridColumn>

And I setup my model with INotifyPropertyChanged:
    public class Team : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Competency> Competencies { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Competency>();

        private ObservableCollection<Competency> _selectedCompetencies = new ObservableCollection<Competency>();
        public ObservableCollection<Competency> SelectedCompetencies
        {
            get => _selectedCompetencies;
            set
            {
                if (_selectedCompetencies != value)
                {
                    _selectedCompetencies = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedCompetencies));
                }
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    
    }

public class Competency : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _isSelected;
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Ordinal { get; set; }
    public char State { get; set; }

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get => _isSelected;
        set
        {
            if (_isSelected != value)
            {
                _isSelected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsSelected));
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}


It lists correctly dropdown, but it wont bind selected items.
I currently test it through my constructor with some dummy data:
public partial class TeamsAdmin : Page
{
    public ObservableCollection<Team> TeamsItems { get; set; }// = new ObservableCollection<Team>();
    public ObservableCollection<Models.Competency> Competencies { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Models.Competency>();
    public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();

    public TeamsAdmin()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        // Sample data
        var competencies = new ObservableCollection<Competency>
        {
            new Competency { Id = "1", Name = "Leadership", IsSelected=true },
            new Competency { Id = "2", Name = "Communication", IsSelected = true },
            new Competency { Id = "3", Name = "Problem Solving", IsSelected = true }
        };

        var teamA = new Team
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Team A",
            Competencies = competencies,
            SelectedCompetencies = new ObservableCollection<Competency> { competencies[0], competencies[1] }
        };

        TeamsItems = new ObservableCollection<Team> { teamA };
    }
    }


